# Can't see NULL values in created VIEW using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

When creating view in MySQL I can't see rows with NULL values in created view.

Here we can see table `mail_prijava` 
[image]

and table `status`

[image]

So, I wanted to create VIEW from table `mail_prijava` and table `status` using SQL code below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
v_mail_prijava_test
AS
SELECT
mail_prijava.id,
mail_prijava.naselje AS naselje,
mail_prijava.ulica AS ulica,
mail_prijava.email AS email,
mail_prijava.napomena AS napomena,
IFNULL(status.opis AS "test") AS status
DATE_FORMAT(datum_unosa, "%d.%m.%Y.") AS datum_servisa,
vrijeme_unosa
FROM mail_prijava
INNER JOIN status ON status.id = mail_prijava.status_id
```

When using code above I get this table:
[image]

Problem is that row with null value from table `mail_prijava` is not showing and I'm wondering why is that and is it possible to show rows with NULL in created view.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all rows, including those that don't have any matches in the `status` table you need to use a `left join` instead of the `inner join`.

Change this:

```
INNER JOIN status ON status.id = mail_prijava.status_id
```

To this:

```
LEFT JOIN status ON status.id = mail_prijava.status_id
```

Also, your IFNULL line looks odd, you probably want:

```
IFNULL(status.opis, "test") AS status -- this will show "test" as status if it's null
```